# How to add number to wordpress count function?

Tags: functions, users

I am using a function on wordpress that accurately counts registered users. How could I edit this function code to add a number to the counter? For example, so it outputs registered users + 100.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
<?php
        $result = count_users();
        echo 'There are <b>', $result['total_users'], '</b> total
users.';
        ?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Er, `echo $result['total_users'] + 100;` ?

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I knew it had to be something simple. I kept putting the 100 in the bracket. Noob mistake.